# Is it possible to add weightage to integer values in mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Let's say I have a collection with the following schema:

```
title: String,
description: String,
upvotes: Int32
```

I want to be able to search for documents within this schema by title or by description where title has more weightage than the description. But I also want to be able to add some sort of weightage to the upvotes but not in an index way, in a bigger the better way.

I have tried searching by the title and description first and then sorting by the amount of upvotes:

```
postModel.find({ $text: { $search: req.query.query, $caseSensitive: false } }).sort([['upvotes', 'descending']])
```

The issues with this is that I get really inaccurate results at the top since some documents have very few similarities with the query provided but have a ton of upvotes compared to the more accurate results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of digging through the mongodb documentation I don't think this is possible. I instead just used a search engine called meilisearch (https://www.meilisearch.com/) to accomplish what I wanted.